# Understanding difference between classical and quantum harmonic oscillator probability distributions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, harmonic-oscillator, probability

[image]

Here we have an example QHO wavefunction squared in blue overlayed an equivalent CHO probability distribution. I'm trying to understand intuitively why the QHO result has zeros, i.e. points where we would not detect a particle.

Can one imagine the quantum result as somehow a 'bound particle wave interfering with itself and thus producing this interference pattern' as a reason for this?

For this case, the classical probability is defined as
$$P_{\text{cl}}(x)dx=2\frac{dt}{T},
\quad T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$$

so for
$$x(t)=x_0\sin(\omega t), 
\quad E=\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x_0^2$$

we have
$$P_{\text{cl}}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{x_0^2-x^2}}
=\frac{1}{2\pi\ell\sqrt{\frac{E}{\hbar\omega}-\frac{x^2}{4\ell^2}}}$$

Comment: What do you mean by a probability distribution for a classical harmonic oscillator? A classical harmonic oscillator would be at a definite position at each point in time.

Comment: Sorry, see my edit.